# List item star rating not working when within webpart

Tags: 2010, list, web-part, rating

I have a page containing two webparts, nothing else. The first web part contains a list with item ratings. The second web part contains a different list, also with item ratings.

My issue is that the first list's ratings work fine, but the second list's ratings don't work properly within the web-part.

It seems that after adding a few items, something happens and all items after a certain point can no longer be rated from that web-part. Hovering over the stars shows nothing, and clicking does nothing.

Observe below:

This item can be rated:
[image: Rating hover working]

The next item cannot be rated:
[image: Rating hover NOT working]

I have tried making a new view for the web-part, deleting all items, disabling and re-enabling ratings, making a whole new page, but nothing fixes it except removing the first web-part!
Once the ratings stop working, I have to delete the list and make another. Sometimes I can create 5 items before it stops working, sometimes only 2. I don't see a pattern.

Note that the items *can* be rated when directly viewing the list, but the list is not meant to be used that way, only via web-part.